# How to add a light to a live-action scene?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

Is it possible to add a 3D light to a live action shot to "relight" the plate? say I want to add a colored light to a shot in Cycles to a live-action scene that is lit with a Tungsten light.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and show an image that illustrates what you want to achieve?